# from dynamic html post json ajax with mvc c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I am facing problem posting data from dynamic generated html to ASP.NET Controller using HttpClient. The problem is that i post invalid JSON data , i miss generating correct json on c# , because HTML form does not include that part when it is generated. i think i have to deal with nested json but still not sure what happens.
I have this JSON from where i generate HTML form on ASP.NET core.

```
    "inputs": [
        {
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "inputs": [],
                    "type": "TEXT",
                    "description": null,
                    "name": "name",
                    "multiple": false
                }
            ],
            "type": null,
            "description": null,
            "name": "requestMemebershipInput",
            "multiple": false
        }
    ],
    "constraints": [
        {
            "name": "mandatory_requestMemebershipInput_name",
            "expression": "requestMemebershipInput?.name != null",
            "explanation": "name is mandatory for requestMemeber",
            "inputNames": [
                "requestMemebershipInput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

From this JSON form I generate dynamic html that has only one textbox
For this purpose i use  3 classes.

````
    public class Input2
    {
        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("inputs2")]
        public List<object> inputs { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public object description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public bool multiple { get; set; }
    }




    public class Input
    {
        [JsonProperty("inputs")]
        public IEnumerable<Input2> Input2 { get; set; }
        public object type { get; set; }
        public object description { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool multiple { get; set; }
    }
    public class ContractsInputViewModel
    {

        [JsonProperty("inputs")]
        public List<Input> Inputs { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("constraints")]
        public List<object> constraints { get; set; }

    } ```


parsing and generating the form is done and everything it works ok , The problem strarts when i want to post the data using Httpclient to external url.
I tried postman only the following JSON  sends the data.
````

{
  "requestMemebershipInput" : {
    "name" : "test"
  }
}

````
"name" : "test" // this is the textbox on html ghenerated form
the problem is that when i generate form and pass data on controller i am passing only this format 
```{
  "requestMemebershipInput" : {
    "name" : "test"    
  }
}```

the controller i use for post has this Code 
```  [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Complexi(IFormCollection input2)
        {

            var url = await _bonitaClient.GetData();
            var id = TempData["id"];
            var collection = Request.Form.Keys.ToDictionary(k => k, v => Request.Form[v].ToString());



            using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = false })
            {

                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    var formContent = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                              {"username", "walter.bates"},
                              {"password", "bpm"},
                              {"redirect", "false"}

                            };

                    var listdata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    foreach (var key in input2.Keys)
                    {
                        listdata.Add(key, input2[key]);
                        var value = input2[key];
                    }
                    var lista = Json(listdata);

                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    //Define request data format  
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    //string ids = payload.value.id;
                    string urls = "API/bpm/process/" + id + "/instantiation";
                    string urlr = "API/bpm/process/" + id + "/contract";


                    var result = client.PostAsync("loginservice", new FormUrlEncodedContent(formContent)).Result;

                    // Variable to hold the authentication cookie.

                    // Get the authentication cookie from the login request.4904797668459909207 //6261660325251571593
                    var setCookie = string.Empty;
                    var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, urlr);
                    var st = "";
                    foreach (var header in result.Headers.Where(header => header.Key == "Set-Cookie"))
                    {
                        foreach (var value in header.Value)
                        {
                            st += value + ";";
                        }
                        break; // We only care about the first match.
                    }

                    message.Headers.Add("Cookie", st);
                    //message.Content.Headers.Add("Cookie", st);

                    var Res = await client.SendAsync(message);


                    if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {


                        StringContent jsonp = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                        var processResponse =  Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;



                        var t = await client.PostAsync(urls, jsonp);

                    }

                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
````

AJAX Code

````
        $("#form1").on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var myHeaders = new Headers();
                myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
               urlencoded.append("username", "walter.bates");
               urlencoded.append("password", "bpm");
               urlencoded.append("redirect", "false");
            var formData = $('#form1').serialize();
            //console.log(formData);
            function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
            var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i++;) {
                console.log(getCookie('X-Bonita-API-Token'));
                //catch(error => console.log('error', error));
            };
        };
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Contract/Complexi',
                headers: myHeaders,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                redirect: 'follow',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.message);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            });
        });
        });```
````

Comment: What does var lista = Json(listdata); do?  Why are you saying you are posting dynamic html?  You can either post json or html form NOT BOTH...... Also this line JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista) should take your actual classes NOT json... so lista should be of type ContractsInputViewModel for it be serialized correctly.   Also you are NOT showing the actual problem code.... We need to be able to reproduce the issue to solve it.... So create a smaller reproducible example so we can try it on our own.

Comment: One more thing when you do this:  var t = await client.PostAsync(urls, jsonp) you should NOT do that... You should instead do client.PostAsJsonAsync which is an extension method part of System.Net.Http.Formatting. And this method takes an actual object NOT json... just an object and the method converts it to json for you.

Comment: with var lista= Json(listdata) -  i try to cast values from IFormCollection  in lista variable, , if i assign to lista ContractInputViewModel , i get undefined. I want send json data in this format ``` {
  "requestMemebershipInput" : {
    "name" : "test"    
  }```  when i try put client.PostAsJsonAsync ,says client does not contain definition PostAsJsonAsync, I use .netcore3.1 maybe here i am missing dependecies.

Comment: Yup I explained how to send json already and how to serialize it.   It all depends on how your classes look

Comment: Are you saying that code should look like this, a lot of cases are doing this way,                                                                                var listdata = new Dictionary<string, string>(); foreach (var key in input2.Keys)
                    {  listdata.Add(key, input2[key]);  var value = input2[key];         }
 StringContent jsonp = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listdata), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");var processResponse =  Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;var t = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(urls, jsonp);

Comment: NO! when you use PostAsJsonAsync you pass your actual class in your case an instance of ContractsInputViewModel or whatever your model is... The method will take care of converting a class to JSON

Comment: The point is you should not worry about converting to json... Just create a model that matches what you want to send then pass an instance of that model to PostAsJsonAsync

Comment: do you have idea how to cast Iformcollection and postasjson. please write simple code that handles that what you are saying as you see i have 3 model classes i generated the html from the input2 class , inout 2 is subcollection of inputs , but i need to cast case when contractinputmodel has data, input has data and input2 has data . all those nested calases should be send as json.

Comment: html is not based on kodel.is dynamically generated fromjson schema ,is there any option to share screen i will explain more . burim.ameti2018 skype

Comment: You have to create a class that represents the JSON and populate the properties ..... then you send that class in PostAsJsonAsync

Comment: Could you show complete steps and modify your code to reproduce your problem?The view, the ajax, the expected result?I do not understand what is your exact problem

Comment: Xing Zou there is ajax code that sends data to contoller